# Start an Activity not from an Intent

Tags: android

How can I start an Activity without using an Intent? The only rule I have got is

```
if( var == true ) startActivity();
```

but `startActivity();` needs an Intent as a parameter.

Comment: This isn't possible.  You *have* to use an intent.  Why can't you?

Comment: you are right Kristopher i **have** to use an Intent i just got confused for a moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a new intent for the activity you want to start. depending on where you are you will need the app context thought.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to navigate to a second `Activity` (another page) using an `Intent`.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Also, don't forget to adjust the `AndroidManifest.xml` for each `Activity`.

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="SecondActivity"
                  android:label="@string/second_label">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SECOND" /> //should be namespace of your company I guess
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```